# Debug Logs Explanation

Tags: debugging, logging, apex-webservice, debug, time

I'm trying to understand the debug logs Salesforce provides. There are actually two duration(in ms) for every webservice called.

- One at the top
- One at the bottom giving up split up method wise

[image: Duration at the top]

[image: Duration at the bottom]

The things is in most of the logs the method wise sum doesn't add up to the total duration at the top. ie., the top duration is way more than the split ups.

Is there any other process that might take up the remaining time? Or do we have any explanation for why they are differing?

Thanks in Advance! Peace!

Comment: Those are execution times for each of your methods, and don't include waiting time for responses, etc, just time while code is being processed to transmit or receive data.

Comment: @crmprogdev, do you mean duration at top - sum of code execution time = waiting time alone?

Comment: I'd phrase it more like the numbers below represent actual processing times for each method while the number above represents the total time for entire execution context. Whether you can consider the difference as "waiting" time or something else is difficult to say; instead, I'd only say that it's not time being spent running your methods.

Comment: @crmprogdev, Thanks! I was under the same notion as well. Just wanted to confirm if my assumptions were right.